# DataBinding DataGridView to EF.DbSet, how to send new DataGridView rows to DbSet?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource, ef-model-first

I want to databind my DataGridView control to database through Entity model (created with model first approach), i am using EF 5.0, .NET 4.5 and winforms

**My binding is organized as follows:**

DataGridView->BindingSource->BindingList->EF.DbSet->Database

**The result (problem) is**

1) updates to existing records are working properly

2) **inserts** are sent up to BindingList, but they **ARE NOT** sent to EF.DbSet

*What could be the cause for this and how can I solve this?*

**My code:**

```
    //form level objects
    private BindingList<Person> persons;
    private BindingSource pSource=new BindingSource();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context=new TestEFmodelContainer();
        var p = _context.PersonSet.ToList();
        persons = new BindingList<Person>(p); //getting bindinglist
        persons.AllowEdit = true;
        persons.AllowNew = true;

        pSource.DataSource = persons;
        pSource.AllowNew = true;

        personDataGridView.DataSource = pSource;
    }

    //"Save changes to DB" button
    private void SaveChangesToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this!

Instead of these lines:

```
    persons = new BindingList<Person>(p); //getting bindinglist
    ...
    pSource.DataSource = persons;
```

i use this line:

```
    pSource.DataSource = _context.Persons.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Where Persons is a DbSet<> from my DbContext

And one more thing that that i couldn't figure out was trying to make this work with derived EF model classes - let's say i have a BasePerson class and DerivedPerson class. EF creates DbSet only for BasePerson (that includes all derived instances, that are accessible through OfType method) I couldn't get to work .Local.ToBindingList for these derived classes.

The trick for the derived classes was to add DbSet for those Derived classes in DbContext class!

Comment: Note that calling `_context.Persons.Local.ToBindingList()` may add a [big performance hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223291/ef-4-3-1-and-ef-5-0-dbset-local-is-slower-than-an-actual-database-query).

Comment: However, to add to that, if you're limiting the lifespan of your context (say, to that of the form) and not loading a zillion objects, you might be alright.  This is something that can be determined by just keeping an eye on the performance.